# Google Sheets; Apps Script, click checkbox, to move row to 1 destination sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google Sheets; Script work!, Move Row into new Sheet, from 1 sheet.
I need move checked row, in 2 sheets ("Manual") + ("barcode") to 1 sheet as destination ("AllReg").

Please help

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // The first column has a checkbox

  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "Manual" || r.columnStart != 1 || r.rowStart == 1) return;  
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AllReg");
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,12).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,12));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Manual" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "TRUE"){
    const dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("AllReg");
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 12).moveTo(dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for attention
____________________________________
Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '==' line: 3 file: RegToRCTotal.gs ______________________________________


I need the row to be sent to sheet "AllReg" from both sheet
 "Manual" and sheet "Barcode" whenever the checkmark is made is Ture in any sheet,